# Is it possible to search a node/element in a Heap Binary Tree and display it's children/child?

Tags: algorithm, search, heapsort

It's not an assignment question, I just started learning heap and heapsort in C++ language and I'd like to know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. A given node N's children are at 2N and 2N+1. The same applies to them, and their children until you reach the end of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. A heap tree is a data structure.According to wikipedia,a data structure is a particular way of organizing data in a computer so that it can be used efficiently.So you can always search through the data that you have irrespective of whether it is in the heap form or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A heap is a binary tree data structure and you can search any element in it.

However, unlike a binary search tree, a heap is partially ordered and hence the search is less efficient. In a binary search tree, the average time complexity is O(log n) as you follow a single path from root to leaf.

In the case of heap, you would search through all paths. For a path, the search can be pruned if the element to be searched is greater than the value at a particular node (in the case of maxheap).

Since a heap is an almost complete binary tree(only last level may not be fully filled), the children for any node i are at 2i+1 and 2i+2 locations in an array-based implementation.

See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap